# Flutter 3.7 create different result from before(3.3) and from doc, based on this command `flutter create --template=package <package_name>`

Tags: flutter, dart, package

based on [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) flutter doc :

this line `flutter create --template=package hello`

should produce following content :

- LICENSE
- test/hello_test.dart
- hello.iml
- .gitignore
- .metadata
- pubspec.yaml
- tool.
- README.md
- lib/hello.dart
- .idea/modules.xml, .idea/workspace.xml
- CHANGELOG.md

but when update to flutter 3.7
its generate more content like this following image :

[image]

it create more content like :

- android
- ios
- etc

and give some warning :

> This app is using a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
> To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to migrate this app to the V2 embedding.

**complete log :**

```
PS E:\***\***\****> flutter create --template=package hello
Creating project hello...
Running "flutter pub get" in hello...
Resolving dependencies in hello... (1.8s)
+ async 2.10.0
+ boolean_selector 2.1.1
+ characters 1.2.1
+ clock 1.1.1
+ collection 1.17.0 (1.17.1 available)
+ fake_async 1.3.1
+ flutter 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
+ flutter_lints 2.0.1
+ flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
+ js 0.6.5 (0.6.7 available)
+ lints 2.0.1
+ matcher 0.12.13 (0.12.14 available)
+ material_color_utilities 0.2.0
+ meta 1.8.0 (1.9.0 available)
+ path 1.8.2 (1.8.3 available)
+ sky_engine 0.0.99 from sdk flutter
+ source_span 1.9.1
+ stack_trace 1.11.0
+ stream_channel 2.1.1
+ string_scanner 1.2.0
+ term_glyph 1.2.1
+ test_api 0.4.16 (0.4.18 available)
+ vector_math 2.1.4
Changed 23 dependencies in hello!
This app is using a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to migrate this app to the V2 embedding.
Take a look at the docs for migrating an app:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects
Wrote 13 files.

All done!
Your package code is in hello\lib\hello.dart
```

i search online based on that warning, and not single one solution mention about **package**. my question is Why it is different from before and what should i do about the warning. I need help and your guide, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the warning is wrongly generated as there's no `AndroidManifest.xml` in the package.

About the other issue (platform directories inside the package), i see that is still open: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119844

So, at the moment, there's no solution.

A temporary solution (not suitable for all cases) could be the one discussed here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119844#issuecomment-1414478314

Comment: thanks for your anwser, any tips or some direction to generate it "manually"?

Comment: @SayyidJ : if you have android studio then you can create from it by new -> flutter project